# How to detect multi set words OpenNLP

Tags: java, machine-learning, nlp, opennlp, named-entity-recognition

I'm doing NER using Java OpenNLP and I'm not sure how can I detect multiple words (eg. New York, Bruno Mars, Hong Kong) by using the custom model I have trained.

My training data do cover multi-word spans:

```
<START:place> Hong Kong <END> ... <START:person> Putin <END>
```

I'm pretty sure my trained model and training data are working good. It's just that I do not know how to get the multi-word set. Here is what I did

```
    // testing the model
    NameFinderME nameFinder = new NameFinderME(nameFinderModel);

    String sentence = "India may US to Japan France so Putin should Hong Kong review Trump";
    WhitespaceTokenizer whitespaceTokenizer = WhitespaceTokenizer.INSTANCE;

    // Tokenizing the given paragraph
    String tokens[] = whitespaceTokenizer.tokenize(sentence);
    Span nameSpans[] = nameFinder.find(tokens);
    for (Span s : nameSpans)
        System.out.println(s.toString() + "  " + tokens[s.getStart()]);
```

And here is what I get:

```
[0..1) place  India
[0..1) place  US
[0..1) place  Japan
[0..1) place  France
[0..1) person  Putin
[0..1) place  Hong
[0..1) person  Trump
```

But I want to get [0..1) place  Hong Kong instead of splitting them into two categories.

Thanks.

Comment: Off topic: @USER1223_T, I just noticed your question and I'm looking for people who are experienced in the development of NLP applications. I provide a [framework which aims to make the development of custom NLP models easier](https://gitlab.com/schrieveslaach/NLPf). It is called NLPf and provides, for example, an annotation tool which makes the annotation process much easier. Additionally, the integration of custom NLP models is supported by Maven build process. Do you have same time to experiment with the framework and answer a questionnaire?

Comment: @Schrieveslaach hi, thank you for your information but recently I'm a bit occupied, I will definitely try it when I'm free, and I will let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. You can reach out to me at any time.

Answer (score 1):

I defined an array list to include all the multiple word place name, eg {"Hong", "New", "North", "South" ... } then use it to check if it contains tokens[s.getStart()]. If yes, add `tokens[s.getStart()] + " " + tokens[s.getStart() + 1]` else, add `tokens[s.getStart()]`. Although it's not the best approach but it's enough for me now.